# android transition background of view from one color to another

Tags: android, transition, background-color

I have a view with a black background with transparency: #DD000000

What I want is that the view, in some circumstances, transitions from #223333FF back to the first color.

```
//lastApp.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.semitransparent));
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE), new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK)};
TransitionDrawable trans = new TransitionDrawable(color);
int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
    lastApp.setBackgroundDrawable(trans);
} else {
    lastApp.setBackground(trans);
}
trans.startTransition(300);
```

This code works, but the colors are not the ones I want.

If I use the next line I believe it creates two Black colors, because I don't see any blue, and the transparency is lost.

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)), new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.black_overlay))};
```

My next attempt was using resources without the alpha: #DD000000 -> #000000; #223333FF -> #3333FF
Here the transition worked, but it wasn't what I wanted as there was no transparency.

The next two attemps were simply trying something new, as I want to use color resources.

With the next line I get a black without transparency.

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(0x223333FF), new ColorDrawable(0xDD000000)};
```

This results in a final blueish color, instead of transparent black

```
ColorDrawable[] color = {new ColorDrawable(0x223333FF), new ColorDrawable(0x33000000)};
```

I have also tried, with no effect:

```
color[1].setAlpha(50);
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with `ArgbEvaluator`

```
ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(yourView, "backgroundColor", Color.RED, Color.BLUE).setDuration(3000);
    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    animator.start();
```

Comment: It worked. Nevertheless, it didn't recognise the start() and I had to do it like this:
    ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(lastApp, "backgroundColor", getResources().getColor(R.color.blue_transition), getResources().getColor(R.color.black_overlay_transition));
    animator.setDuration(300);
    animator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
    animator.start();

Do you know why?

Comment: @lotdrops Yes, it is because setEvaluator doesn't return the ObjectAnimator, unlike setDuration. Update answer

Answer (score 0):

ObjectAnimator works from android 3.0 (sdk 11). For previous versions i did next:

```
 private void init(int value){
      int alpha = value*0x1000000;

   ColorDrawable cl1= new           
  ColorDrawable(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.transtion_item1)  
     +alpha);
  ColorDrawable cl2= new   
   ColorDrawable(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.transtion_item2)   
     +alpha);
    TransitionDrawable transition = new TransitionDrawable( new Drawable[]{cl1,cl2});
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<16)
       v.setBackgroundDrawable(transition);
    else
        v.setBackground(transition);
    mTransitionCount=0;
    startCyclicTransition(transition);

}

private void startCyclicTransition(final TransitionDrawable trans){
    if (mTransitionCount >=0) {
        if(mTransitionCount%2==0) {
            trans.startTransition(2000);
        }else {
            trans.reverseTransition(2000);
        }
        mTransitionCount++;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startCyclicTransition(trans);
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```